# Is it possible to change tooltip options known as fieldname in nodegraph?

Tags: grafana

This is my tooltip for the node graph, and in this, I want to change the tooltip names to my desired name for particular fields. Instead of this field for the tooltip, I want to rename it something else. How can I do this?

I am expecting custom tooltip fields from this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to change tooltip name.

As per I understand you are doing this way...

**Go to Dashboard -> Edit Panel -> Click Query Inspector, Click JSON and Edit this way**

```
> “title”: “Panel Title”, 
 “transformations”: [{ 
 “id”: “renameByRegex”,
> “options”: { 
  “regex”: “title”, 
  “renamePattern”: “Product Name” 
}}],
> “type”: “nodeGraph”
```

I Hope this Help For You.